# python interpreter returning blank dictionary after calling imported function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, import, interpreter

I'm trying to learn python (with a VBA background).

I've imported the following function into my interpreter:

```
def shuffle(dict_in_question):  #takes a dictionary as an argument and shuffles it
    shuff_dict = {}
    n = len(dict_in_question.keys())
    for i in range(0, n):
        shuff_dict[i] = pick_item(dict_in_question)
    return shuff_dict
```

following is a print of my interpreter;

```
>>> stuff = {"a":"Dave", "b":"Ben", "c":"Harry"}
>>> stuff
{'a': 'Dave', 'c': 'Harry', 'b': 'Ben'}
>>> decky11.shuffle(stuff)
{0: 'Harry', 1: 'Dave', 2: 'Ben'}
>>> stuff
{}
>>>
```

It looks like the dictionary gets shuffled, but after that, the dictionary is empty.  Why?  Or, am I using it wrong?

Comment: You should include the definition of `pick_item` as well.

Comment: By the way, range(n) is the same as range(0, n)

Comment: How is `pick_item()` implemented?  Does it call `.popitem()` on the dictionary?  That will modify the dictionary passed, so `stuff` will become empty.  One option would be to create a copy in `shuffle()`, `dict_to_use = dict_in_question.copy()`.

Comment: `pick_item()` is probably doing funky things to your dict (like removing items so they don't get picked again).

Comment: I think you're right because pick_item does delete an item as it's picked.  but, the solution below does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign it back to stuff too, as you're returning a new dictionary.

```
>>> stuff = decky11.shuffle(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dogbert's answer solves your immediate problem, but keep in mind that dictionaries don't have an order! There's no such thing as "the first element of my_dict."  (Using .keys() or .values() generates a list, which does have an order, but the dictionary itself doesn't.) So, it's not really meaningful to talk about "shuffling" a dictionary.

All you've actually done here is remapped the keys from letters a, b, c, to integers 0, 1, 2.  These keys have different hash values than the keys you started with, so they print in a different order.  But you haven't changed the order of the dictionary, because the dictionary didn't have an order to begin with.

Depending on what you're ultimately using this for (are you iterating over keys?), you can do something more direct:

```
shufflekeys = random.shuffle(stuff.keys())
for key in shufflekeys:
    # do thing that requires order
```

As a side note, dictionaries (aka hash tables) are a really clever, hyper-useful data structure, which I'd recommend learning deeply if you're not already familiar. A good hash function (and non-pathological data) will give you O(1) (i.e., constant) lookup time - so you can check if a key is in a dictionary of a million items as fast as you can in a dictionary of ten items!  The lack of order is a critical feature of a dictionary that enables this speed.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation.  Do you have a good rec for some reading material on hash tables?

Comment: This is a good, detailed explanation: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx